# MWBC old outlet to new 2 connection outlet usb Cand A

Tags: mwbc

I am updating my outlets to leviton usb A and C outlets.  The new outlets only have hot common and ground.

My old outlet has a white, black and red.

[image]

It appears to have its own breaker from the other outlets around it , however if I put both the black and red into the hot connection it sends power to my other outlets with their breaker off.  Will I have to just add a regular outlet and wire it up the same way, or is there a way to wire this outlet in?

[image]

Comment: If that really is a MWBC, then the tab on the hot side of that outlet should have been removed - is that the case? If it is, then you should have 240V between black and red, and the breakers which supply them *should* at the very least be handle-tied together. If that were the case then you should expect them to immediately trip (hopefully without a bang) as soon as you tried to turn them on together.

Comment: I had a good zap when turning on the breaker.

Comment: I don't see a tab,   it it on the new outlet.  I usually see the tab to remove on traditional outlets, but don't see it on this one.

Comment: There isn't a tab on the new outlet because these fancy outlets with extra functionality cannot be used on a MWBC in the same way that an old outlet can. The new outlet can only take a single hot phase, not 2 separate ones like the old one can (with its tab removed).

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. It's word soup right now, and the USB bits are entirely irrelevant. Also take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers properly.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your guidance.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: @brhans There’s no electrical reason why a USB receptacle with separate terminals for each of the AC receptacles couldn’t exit, it’s just a matter of space - there isn’t room for extra terminals and the electronics in a single-gang package. It could be done in a two-gang package but that would be a waste of space.

Comment: @nobody as far as I'm aware, no such USB (or GFCI, etc) outlet with receptacles which can be separated  does actually exist. Sure there's no electrical reason to make it impossible - but this is DIY, not WorldBuilding so it doesn't seem like confusing the OP with theoreticals would be helpful ...

Comment: Yes, I agree none exist. I just wanted to clarify that the reason for that is purely physical size constraints, not anything electrical as the "cannot be used on a MWBC" wording seemed to imply.

Answer (score 4):

### If that's a MWBC

Well, you seem to have a handle on the MWBC term.  That may be it.  If that's a MWBC, that would mean the red and black wire land on different circuit breakers in the panel - and by *modern* Code those two breaker handles should be tied.  (it may also be a 2-pole breaker, which looks like 2 breakers tied, except on "QO" where it just [looks weird](https://youtu.be/jMmUoZh3Hq4?t=164).)

Also, importantly, they must be phased correctly - with 240V across red and black.  If they're not, the neutral will overload.    The purpose of the handle-tie is to protect maintainers, so you're assured of turning off *the whole* circuit. But use of a UL-Listed handle-tie on a panel not made by FPE, Zinsco or GE, will also tend to assure you phase them correctly.  If you are comfortable working inside your panel I strongly urge you to check, confirm their phasing, reposition them to be adjacent and handle-tie them.  And check the rest of the panel - if there's one MWBC, there's five.

if you're not comfortable in the panel but they're adjacent, well installing a UL-Listed approved handle-tie involves opening up the panel, so I'd say violate code and bend your own handle-tie using a bit of bare #12 wire.

Now with a MWBC, think about your use of this outlet.  If you install two high-power appliances in here, then you may need it to be a MWBC.  It's not a good candidate for a "fancy outlet", none of which support splitting the hot wires to be separately fed.  Assume all heat-making kitchen appliances are "high power" - except for refrigerators, oddly. They make a lot of heat, but [they cheat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFEHFsO-XSI) - they only use 120 watts  (1 amp) to do it :)

If you don't really use high power here, then you can "cap off" one of the two hot wires and use the other one alone.   To cap off a wire, choose a wire nut [certified](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFEHFsO-XSI) for one (1) wire of your size, generally a size or two smaller than you're used to using. I also recommend bending the wire over 180 degrees and taping the nut on so it can't get loose.

### Or it might be a switch leg

Another common use of red-black to a receptacle is where the receptacle is split - one side to operate under the command of a light switch, and the other side to be always-hot.  If you install the fancy receptacle in this situation, you won't be able to split the receptacle anymore - you'll need to decide whether you want the receptacle switched with the switch, or always-hot.  And as above, use one wire and cap the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Your old outlet is a typical 1/2 switched outlet.  Most likely the black wire is always hot when the breaker is on and the red wire is fed by a wall switch somewhere in the room.  The usual location is by a door or doorway into the room.

It is difficult to tell, but it does appear that the tab or "bridge" between the  2 screws on the hot side is removed. Example shown in the pic:[image: Bridge or tab]
This is why when you put both the black and red in the one new outlet it powers the other outlets.

There are 2 things you can do:

A: purchase an outlet that has the usb you want but can be unbridged for the red and black wires.

B: Find which one of the 2 wires is switched, red or black. ( don't take the assumption that it is red) and cap the end with a wirenut and neatly tuck it in the back of the box. Then only attach the black wire, neutral (white) and ground to the appropriate screws.

Comment: All the evidence (“it sends power to my other outlets with their breaker off”) points to MWBC, not half-switched on the same circuit. Your A is not an option because such a thing is not produced.

Comment: @nobody,  Telling the OP that they have a MWBC means nothing to them, as they are confused as to how to overcome their problem.  The solutions remain the same.  Solution "A" was 100% feasible. It is in theory. I gave no guarantee in finding the device.

Comment: The OP knows enough about MWBCs to mention it in the original post (title). Saying that the situation might be something that the evidence says it probably isn't is not helpful (and arguably *dangerous* since MWBCs need extra precautions that an "ordinary" half-switched receptacle does not). Mentioning your solution "A" is a complete waste of time, because such a thing does not exist.